# JavaScript PNG drawing function with inline styling not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need your help. I'm currently trying to apply a part of this answered SO question to a library I'm using to generate a PNG:

[How can I colour different words in the same line with HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904201/how-can-i-colour-different-words-in-the-same-line-with-html5-canvas/43904751#43904751)

This is how I call my function:

```
let fs       = require('fs');
let text2png = require('text2png');
let text     = '{#ff0000ES}KISTAFÜNF\nZEHNZWANZIG\nDREIVIERTEL\nVORFUNKNACH\nHALBEALFÜNF\nEINSXAMZWEI\nDREIPMJVIER\nSECHSNLACHT\nSIEBENZWÖLF\nZEHNEUNKUHR';

text = text.split('').join(' '); // Fake letter spacing

fs.writeFileSync('test2.png', text2png(text,
    {
        color: 'gray',
        textAlign: 'center',
        lineSpacing: 30,
        font: '100px sans-serif'
    }
));
```

This is the `text2png` function which I modified:

```
const text2png = (text, options = {}) => {
    // Options
    options = parseOptions(options);

    // Register a custom font
    if (options.localFontPath && options.localFontName) {
        registerFont(options.localFontPath, {family: options.localFontName});
    }

    const canvas = createCanvas(0, 0);
    const ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const max = {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        ascent: 0,
        descent: 0
    };

    let lastDescent;
    const lineProps = text.split("\n").map(line => {
        ctx.font      = options.font;
        const metrics = ctx.measureText(line);

        const left    = -1 * metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft;
        const right   = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight;
        const ascent  = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent;
        const descent = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;

        max.left    = Math.max(max.left, left);
        max.right   = Math.max(max.right, right);
        max.ascent  = Math.max(max.ascent, ascent);
        max.descent = Math.max(max.descent, descent);
        lastDescent = descent;

        return {line, left, right, ascent, descent};
    });

    const lineHeight = max.ascent + max.descent + options.lineSpacing;

    const contentWidth  = max.left + max.right;
    const contentHeight =
              lineHeight * lineProps.length -
              options.lineSpacing -
              (max.descent - lastDescent);

    canvas.width =
        contentWidth +
        options.borderLeftWidth +
        options.borderRightWidth +
        options.paddingLeft +
        options.paddingRight;

    canvas.height =
        contentHeight +
        options.borderTopWidth +
        options.borderBottomWidth +
        options.paddingTop +
        options.paddingBottom;

    const hasBorder =
              false ||
              options.borderLeftWidth ||
              options.borderTopWidth ||
              options.borderRightWidth ||
              options.borderBottomWidth;

    if (hasBorder) {
        ctx.fillStyle = options.borderColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    if (options.backgroundColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = options.backgroundColor;
        ctx.fillRect(
            options.borderLeftWidth,
            options.borderTopWidth,
            canvas.width - (options.borderLeftWidth + options.borderRightWidth),
            canvas.height - (options.borderTopWidth + options.borderBottomWidth)
        );
    } else if (hasBorder) {
        ctx.clearRect(
            options.borderLeftWidth,
            options.borderTopWidth,
            canvas.width - (options.borderLeftWidth + options.borderRightWidth),
            canvas.height - (options.borderTopWidth + options.borderBottomWidth)
        );
    }

    ctx.font        = options.font;
    ctx.fillStyle   = options.textColor;
    ctx.antialias   = "gray";
    ctx.textAlign   = options.textAlign;
    ctx.lineWidth   = options.strokeWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.strokeColor;

    let offsetY = options.borderTopWidth + options.paddingTop;
    lineProps.forEach(lineProp => {
        // Calculate Y
        let x = 0;
        let y = max.ascent + offsetY;

        // Calculate X
        switch (options.textAlign) {
            case "start":
            case "left":
                x = lineProp.left + options.borderLeftWidth + options.paddingLeft;
                break;

            case "end":
            case "right":
                x =
                    canvas.width -
                    lineProp.left -
                    options.borderRightWidth -
                    options.paddingRight;
                break;

            case "center":
                x = contentWidth / 2 + options.borderLeftWidth + options.paddingLeft;
                break;
        }

        let i                 = 0;
        let inlineColorMarker = '{}';
        let state             = [];
        let subText           = '';

        while (i < lineProp.line.length) {
            let letter       = lineProp.line[i];
            let wordCharCode = lineProp.line.charCodeAt(i);

            if (wordCharCode < 256) {
                if (inlineColorMarker.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
                    if (subText !== '') {
                        renderText(subText);
                        subText = '';
                    }

                    if (letter === '{') {   // Word color delimiter
                        state.push({
                            textColor: options.textColor,
                            x: x,
                            y: y,
                        });

                        var t = text[i];

                        console.log(t);

                        if (t === '#') {
                            console.log(text.substr(i, 7));
                            options.textColor = text.substr(i, 7);

                            i += 6;
                        }
                    } else if (letter === '}') {
                        var s = state.pop();

                        y                 = s.y;
                        options.textColor = s.textColor;
                    }
                } else {
                    subText += letter;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }

        function renderText(text) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = options.textColor;
            ctx.translate(x, y)
            // ctx.scale(scale, scale)
            ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);

            if (options.strokeWidth > 0) {
                ctx.strokeText(lineProp.line, x, y);
            }

            ctx.restore();
        }

        // ctx.fillText(lineProp.line, x, y);

        // if (options.strokeWidth > 0) {
        //     ctx.strokeText(lineProp.line, x, y);
        // }

        offsetY += lineHeight;
    });

    switch (options.output) {
        case "buffer":
            return canvas.toBuffer();
        case "stream":
            return canvas.createPNGStream();
        case "dataURL":
            return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        case "canvas":
            return canvas;
        default:
            throw new Error(`output type:${options.output} is not supported.`);
    }
};

function parseOptions(options) {
    return {
        font: or(options.font, "30px sans-serif"),
        textAlign: or(options.textAlign, "left"),
        textColor: or(options.textColor, options.color, "black"),
        backgroundColor: or(options.bgColor, options.backgroundColor, null),
        lineSpacing: or(options.lineSpacing, 0),

        strokeWidth: or(options.strokeWidth, 0),
        strokeColor: or(options.strokeColor, "white"),

        paddingLeft: or(options.paddingLeft, options.padding, 0),
        paddingTop: or(options.paddingTop, options.padding, 0),
        paddingRight: or(options.paddingRight, options.padding, 0),
        paddingBottom: or(options.paddingBottom, options.padding, 0),

        borderLeftWidth: or(options.borderLeftWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderTopWidth: or(options.borderTopWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderBottomWidth: or(options.borderBottomWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderRightWidth: or(options.borderRightWidth, options.borderWidth, 0),
        borderColor: or(options.borderColor, "black"),

        localFontName: or(options.localFontName, null),
        localFontPath: or(options.localFontPath, null),

        output: or(options.output, "buffer")
    };
}

function or() {
    for (let arg of arguments) {
        if (typeof arg !== "undefined") {
            return arg;
        }
    }
    return arguments[arguments.length - 1];
}

module.exports = text2png;
```

Somehow I'm missing something because it's just drawing the first line and also without any colors in the first 2 letters:

[image]

Comment: First, you missed a `i += 1` before `t = text[ i ]`, then, their `text` is not *your* `text`, so you'd want `t = lineProp.line[ i ]`, then ... I don't have more time to go farther, but basically, nothing a coffee and a strong reading can overcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes.

At top of code (very first line) add the directive `"use strict";`  This would have throw an error where the problem is.

In the while loop you have

> ```
> var t = text[i];  // no such thing as text
>                   // i pointing to wrong position
>
> console.log(t);
>
> if (t === '#') {
>     console.log(text.substr(i, 7));  // text is undefined
>     options.textColor = text.substr(i, 7); // text is undefined
>
>     i += 6; // wrong step as i has wrong value
> }
> ```

Change to

```
       if (lineProp.line[i + 1] === '#') {
           options.textColor = lineProp.line.substr(++i, 7); // must be ++i DO NOT use i++
           i += 6;
       }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! But somehow it's not printing out the other lines now. Any idea? Like `ZEHNZWANZIG` and so on. Update: Also the coloring seems to be not correct. The result with the fixed code can be found above.

Comment: @Mr.Jo You have made way to many changes to the function to make a simple fix and there is no way for me to test any suggested changes to your code without a lot of work. What is missing is the newline marker `"\n"` and the code to takes action when a newline is found, however your code splits the input string on new lines and as such the newline is  removed.

Comment: With your help I've managed to do an inline styling. Now I need to find a way to improve the letter spacing. Thanks a lot for your help!